# Iwasawa decomposition of SU(1,1)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-decomposition

Does anyone know how the Iwasawa decomposition of $SU(1,1)=KAN$ and the centralizer $M$ of $A$ in $K$ looks like?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: $SU(1,1)\cong SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ so one can optain the Iwasawa decomposition by using the Iwasawa decomposition of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, right?

Edit: My definition of $SU(n,1)$ is $$SU(n,1):=\{f:\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\text{ linear}\mid Q(f(x))=Q(x)\ \forall x\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\text{ and }\det(f)=1\}$$ where $Q$ is the quadratic form defined by $Q(x):=|x_1|^2+\ldots+|x_n|^2-|x_{n+1}|^2$.

Comment: What's your definition of $SU(1,1)$?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I edited my question.

Comment: By the way: Is there some book where one can look up the Iwasawa decompositions of classical rank one groups?

Answer (score 3):

The maximal parabolic subgroup is of the form
$$
M(a,b)=A N =\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
0&a^{-1}\end{array}\right)
$$
with
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0 \\
0&a^{-1}\end{array}\right)\, ,\qquad 
N= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & b \\
0&1\end{array}\right)\, .
$$

$SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ elements are then of the form of
$SO(2)M(a, b)$ where $SO(2)$ contains elements of the form
$$
K=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}
\right)
$$
There are some details in [this student project](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ereichst/Cartan+Iwasawa.pdf) by S. Jana:

> Jana, Subhajit, "Cartan and Iwasawa Decompositions in
> Lie Theory." University of British Columbia 102: 105.

As to your comment regarding a look up table, see table 1 of [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82054351.pdf):

> Sawyer, P., 2016. Computing the Iwasawa decomposition of the classical Lie groups of noncompact type using the QR decomposition. Linear Algebra and its Applications, 493, pp.573-579